# How do I stage all files at once in Git Gui?

Tags: git, staging, git-gui

I have just created a GIT on a folder. I now want to add the contents of that folder by "staging" all the files.  In the GUI, is there a way to select all the files. I have well over 4000 files and clicking one at a time is proving to be a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Yes**,

Select the items (select top one hit shift, select bottom one) and hit <kbd>CTRL T</kbd>

Or go to commit -> stage to commit

Comment: There are days when my mind seems to be smaller than my butt, but strangely full of the same thing :)

Comment: @baash, no big deal, it took me a while to find that setting its kind of hidden, I was expecting right click to work.

Comment: Ah. Thanks a lot. The operation "Stage to Commit" (Ctrl+T) wasn't informative for me. I thought it meant take whatever's listed under Staged Changes and commit them.

Comment: I agree "Stage to Commit" is not indicative of the operation it is about to perform. It should be called "Unstaged to Staged"

Comment: Bless you for answering this. Saved me lots of clicking misery!

Comment: @Brad Or perhaps "Stage in order to Commit"

Answer (score 5):

Quite late, but one method is to add an option in the 'Tools' menu.

1. Click 'Tools'>Add...
2. Name it whatever you want (I chose 'add all')
3. In the 'Command' field, type `git add *`
4. Optionally check the boxes to remove a dialog window, output window, and global configuration.
5. Click the `Add` button in the bottom right.

Now, click Tools>Add all and all changes will be staged. Hope this helps!

Comment: is there a way to add multiple commands on a single name?

Comment: @MetaSnarf Indeed, bash syntax can be used to merge multiple commands. So `&&` can be placed between each command, where each next command only runs if the previous succeeds. Example: `git add . && git commit -m "test commit"` will both stage and commit your current changes with the message "test commit"