# How can I commit many new files with git gui without clicking each of it?

Tags: git, git-gui, git-commit

I have a ton of new files to commit. Clicking each one in git gui (Windows) to stage is annoying.

How can I can I commit a whole bunch of files at once?

Comment: already answered! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344908/git-gui-stage-everything

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use the gui ^^ ... a `git add .` will add all new files to the index.

Answer (score 18):

A nice answer from [@Sam Saffron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron) to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344908/git-gui-stage-everything) states

> Select the items (select top one, hit shift, select bottom one) and hit <kbd>CTRL T</kbd>
>
> Or go to commit -> stage to commit

Answer (score 5):

I think if you high light them all and type ctrl+t, then you should stage all the selected files, although I find one normally gets left over for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [GIT Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) for a different GUI - I find it pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed, you can type `git commit -m 'whatever'` after you have added the changes to the staging area. To do a mass add do the following: `git add .`

this is, of course, done in the command prompt

Answer (score 1):

In Git Gui, You can stage all files at once with menu option:

`commit` > `Stage changed files to commit`

or shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>