# Git not showing updated css and html files as changed

Tags: git

I am having a problem with the Git Gui on vista. If I modify a .php file I can click "rescan"  and the files will show as changed and then I can commit the file in question. However when I modify any HTML or CSS file I do not get this option.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Check if you have these files in .gitignore

Comment: Sorry a bit new git how do I do that ?

Comment: Just looked in the file and it says # git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~

Comment: Check the .gitignore file at the root of the repository, not just the .git/info/exclude file.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with github. Might want to change the title and tag.

Comment: I have added !*.html !*.css !*.php to the .gitignore file but still no joy

Comment: Are the files in the same repository? Do you have a system wide ignore  file? Have they ever been included in the repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are those `html` and `css` files tracked? (i.e. have they been added and committed before?)
Because if they aren't, [git-gui shows untracked files as "changed but not updated"](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/2/14/238747).

And you cannot commit untracked files. You should have the option to add them though.

For EGit (Git in Eclipse), see [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#team_operations), as well as [Eclipse wiki EGit tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Recording_Changes_in_the_Repository):

> Each file in the working directory can either be tracked or untracked.

- Tracked files are those which were in the last snapshot or files which have been newly staged into the index. They can be unmodified, modified, or staged.
- Untracked files are all other files which were not in the last snapshot and have not been added to the index.

> When you first clone a repository all files in the working directory will be tracked and unmodified since they have been freshly checked out and you didn't start editing them yet.
>
> As you edit files git will recognize they are modified since you have modified them since the last commit. You stage the modified files into the index and then commit the staged changes and the cycle repeats.

[image]

Comment: No never committed. How can I track a file ?

Comment: @user563771: If you are talking about this "git gui": http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/tour.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344908/git-gui-stage-everything. If you are talking about a Git gui integrated in another tool, like Eclipse EGit: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#team_operations

Comment: Thanks, I use eclipse as my IDE so might be a handy link

Comment: @user563771: ok I have added another tutorial link and a picture of Git workflow in term of tracking changes.